# How to use DataTables font awesome icons?

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using `DataTables` and instead of using images for the pagination buttons I decided to use icons. I used the [**Bootstrap Font awesome CDN**](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css) which works perfectly fine but in a proxy server, for some reason, the file throws `404` but the `DataTables` CDN loads properly. From the DataTables documentation I found that DataTables has its own font-awesome meaning embedded one which is as follows:

Here is the fiddle [JSFiddle][1]

```
cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/integration/font-awesome/dataTables.fontAwesome.css
```

Bootstrap CDN has the fa-forward etc classes for the fonts but in the DataTables CDN I couldn't find any so how can I add the icons for the pagination.

JQuery

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
 pagingType: 'input',
 pageLength: 5,
 language: {
 oPaginate: {
   sNext: '<i class="fa fa-forward"></i>',
   sPrevious: '<i class="fa fa-backward"></i>',
   sFirst: '<i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i>',
   sLast: '<i class="fa fa-step-forward"></i>'
   }
   }   
  })
```

Using `DataTables` font awesome how can I add the classes in my Jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code

Hope this will helps You.

**Edit**

Here you can use `full_numbers` instead of `input` else it will throw error like

> Cannot read property 'fnInit' of undefined.

And in your given font-awesome library there is a no such fonts which you want to use. So use other instead.

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
    
     language: {
      oPaginate: {
          sNext: '<i class="fa fa-forward"></i>',
          sPrevious: '<i class="fa fa-backward"></i>',
          sFirst: '<i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i>',
          sLast: '<i class="fa fa-step-forward"></i>' 
      }
      
   } ,
   pagingType: 'full_numbers',
   pageLength: 5
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="example">
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Subscriber ID</th>
            <th>Install Location</th>
            <th>Subscriber Name</th>
            <th>some data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

In Your given CDN

```
table.dataTable thead th.sorting:after,
table.dataTable thead th.sorting_asc:after,
table.dataTable thead th.sorting_desc:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    right: 8px;
    display: block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Here you see that your cdn inherits the `fontawesome` font family

So if you can't use direct `fontawesome CDN` than download it locally and upload on your server it will helps you.

Comment: Nirav, I don't want to use bootstrap CDN, I want to use the other CDN I described in my question.

Comment: @David in this cdn `https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/integration/font-awesome/dataTables.fontAwesome.css` there is a no fonts which you want to use. check that url by opening it in your new tab you will realize that.

Comment: This is what I am looking for, how can I add icons using datatables font awesome CDN

Comment: This is the list of icons in DataTables font awesome and the icons for forward and previous buttons are there. http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Comment: I knew that this CDN doesn't have those classes, so in this case I still need to use the same Bootstrap Font-Awesome CDN and just change the pagingType to full_numbers.

Comment: I am using input type for a purpose though to show the page numbers.

Answer (score 2):

For people coming here for sort icons, DataTables actually has an old blog post about this: https://datatables.net/blog/2014-06-06

Basically you can override the rules from `datatables.css` in your own CSS like below:

```css
table.dataTable thead .sorting:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting:after {
  content: '\f0dc';
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after {
  content: '\e155';
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after {
  content: '\e156';
}
```

Comment: This worked for me EXCEPT I had to use `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";` since I am referencing Font Awesome 5 on a Pro Account.  Looks like you can also use `Font Awesome 5 Free` and a few other options found here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements